# Group InfluxDB Data by day in Grafana is shifted by one day

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I want to display my power consumption in grafana which is connected to Influx DB. I use time group by (1d) but the result is not what I expect. It looks like grafana calculates a time frame of 24 hours an then display the value as the value of the last timeframe, which is then unfortunately the first hour of the next day. So all values are shifted one day.

**Grafana Graph of power consumption**
[image]

My Grafana query is:

```
SELECT difference(distinct("value")) FROM "Stromzaehler_Zaehlerstand" WHERE time >= now() - 2d GROUP BY time(1d) tz('Europe/Berlin‘)
```

The additionally displayed consumption per hour has the following query.

```
SELECT difference(distinct("value")) FROM "Stromzaehler_Zaehlerstand" WHERE time >= now() - 2d GROUP BY time(1h) fill(null) tz('Europe/Berlin‘)
```

Additionally no bar is shown for the usage of today so far. I think this is due to the shift which results in a bar representing the consumption for today but displayed as of tomorrow.

I have done similar queries/graphs in grafana with elasticsearch but InfluxDB seems to work different here.

Comment: i have the same issue with mysql as database. did you resolve this?